# DVD writer on Sony laptop fails to recognize blank discs as writable

Tags: windows-7, drivers, dvd, compact-disc, burning

I have a problem with my DVD-Writer:
[image]

- When I insert a CD or DVD in it to play or to browse my data, it is recognized without any problem.

[image]

But when I insert a blank DVD or CD to write, it doesn't recognize it? We hear that the disk is rotating in the drive but nothing changes and if I startn to use [Ashampoo Burning Studio](https://www.ashampoo.com/en/usd/pin/7110/burning-software/burning-studio-free) and write on it, it shows that the drive is empty.

[image]

I thought that it may be because of using old driver software versions. But my laptop is **[VPCCW-1NFX/B](https://docs.sony.com/release//specs/VPCCW1NFXB_mksp.pdf)** and its optical Drive characteristics are:

[image]

Which doesn't support drivers for it any more?
So the only drivers that I have are the ones that I downloaded several years ago from the following URL:

```
http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=VPCCW1NFXB&template_id=1&region_id=1&tab=download#/downloadTab.
```

- Optiarc BD ROM BC-5500S4 Firmware Update ---> OPFOPD-00208302-1060 **(last modification date: 2/20/2013)**
- Optiarc DVD RW AD-7700S Firmware Update ---> OPFOPD-00209572-1040 **(last modification date: 10/15/2013)**
- PIONEER BD-ROM BDC-TD01 Firmware Update ---> PIFOPD-00221882-1060 **(last modification date: 2/20/2013)**

I've shown the computer to the technicians of the SONY corporation representative in Iran and they say there's no problem with the hardware. Then:

1. What's the problem?
2. If you think the problem is because of the outdated version of driver software, where can I find and download the latest one?

I don't know if this will help or not but the following is a photo of the back and front of my optical drive with wat is written on them beneath them.

[image]

I use CD/DVD media of different brands but most of them are [PRINCO](http://www.princo.com.tw/www/english/profile.htm), SONY and [VEVO](http://www.vevovision.com/en/index.html). I don't think the question may be related to the media.

Comment: I am not sure the drivers are the origin of your problem, but you can find the most up-to-date version using driverscloud.com. It needs you to install a detection software on your PC, but it can be trusted and saved my life several times. Also, if you have any doubt about your optical drive, look at the tray to make sure the logos actually are "CD-RW" and "DVD-RW".

Comment: @JakeGould What do you mean by the media? the contents of the CDs or DVDs or the producer of them?

Comment: @NathanShiraini driverscloud.com? Is there any way to download the most updated version of the driver from the producer's site? like the action that I've done before for [my graphic card](http://goo.gl/q7eg3j)? In fact I'm in Iran and I can only use the websites that offer free services. because of not having access to international payment methods. What detection software do you recommend? I don't understand what do you mean by `tray`? the label of those blank CD or DVDs that I am trying to write on? or the specifications of my optical drives?

Comment: @NathanShiraini In fact [I've shared the specification of my laptop in the question](https://goo.gl/hfBNDa) and the photo shows that it supports `CD Support: Read / Write (CD/-R/-RW)` and `DVD Support: Read / Write (DVD±R/±RW/±R DL/-RAM)`.

Comment: @JakeGould used what I could find easily in the market. 2nd: yes, I've always used this burner and that worked before. the problem has just been risen for about 2 or 3 months. 3rd: I think the 1st response is an answer for the 3rd, too. I really appreciate your help. I really need this feature these days and I can't borrow my sister's laptop because she's busy with her exams, now.

Comment: try downloading "imgburn" and see if the problem persists with another program, that will narrow it down, same problem? it's the disc drive, search the make / model followed by the word drivers into google and the first result should be the correct one, i would not use any "driver solution" software as they tend to do more damage then good.

Comment: @RyanIG I didn't understand this part of your comment? `it's the disc drive, search the make / model followed by the word drivers into google and the first result should be the correct one,` what should I search? the manufacturer of my optical drive or the manufacturer of the discs (CDs or DVDs that I'm using)....I'll download the software that you mentioned but I'm rather sure that the burner is not the problem. Because it is my optical drive that doesn't recognize the blank discs....and if you double click on it without even opening the burner program, there's the message `Please insert a`

Comment: @sepideh https://esupport.sony.com/US/p/swu-download.pl?mdl=VGNNW270F&upd_id=5172&os_group_id=6 that's the official firmware update for your drive, try installing that and see if it changes anything.

Comment: @RyanIG `disc into Drive F:.`, in spite of that there already exists a blank disk in the Drive and ejects the disc. Also did you read my answers to the previous comments? I'm going to add them to my question

Comment: @RyanIG and these two links ([link1](https://goo.gl/sjbl2t) and [link2](https://goo.gl/p6z9Uf))are the other firmware updates that were available when the drivers of my model `VPCCW1NFX/B` were supported in [this link](https://goo.gl/Ey1Dxi), I mean that sony support has listed all of them in the CD/DVD Drives subcategory just like what is shown in [this photo](http://s6.picofile.com/file/8257216900/Capture.JPG). Do I need to install all the 3 files or just the one that you mentioned?

Comment: @JakeGould so how should I ask? you can edit the question to the form that is appropriate. I just didn't add the answer to your comment in the question because I wasn't sure what was your question but I'll add them now and delete the extra parts. But please don't downvote so easily, I may get blocked of asking. I have stated exactly **1- what is the problem? 2- If the problem is with the firmware update then where can I find the latest update** so why do you say it's too broad? I'll edit the question now and I'll ask your opinion

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uninstalling the CD/DVD burner from the hardware manager, rebooting and letting the computer re-install the drivers? 
Also, in the version of Ashampoo that I used to use, under the *settings* menu, there was an entry to *enable* *extended drive enumeration* (or something similar). This somehow forced the program to see or recognize and use older or problematic drives.