# Installing Pioneer BD-ROM BDC-TD01 Firmware Updater: Target is not found?

Tags: windows-7, boot, drivers, dvd, firmware

As you see in the device manager list of my `SONY VPCCW1NFX/B` laptop, there's only the `Optiarc BD-ROM BC-5500S4` device available under the `DVD/CD-ROM drivers` subcategory. where their should be another option named `Pioneer BD-ROM BCD-TD01` available, too.

In fact the first one allows me to read `CD/DVD/Bluray Discs` and the latter one is for writing on such media. **But seems that my windows7x64SP1 doesn't recognize the device**

[image: Device manager list]

Also when I try to [install Firmware updater](https://esupport.sony.com/US/p/swu-download.pl?mdl=VPCL116FX&upd_id=5891&os_group_id=6), I can continue until the **step 7** without any problem but after pressing `Yes`, I get the error, `Target is not found` as it is shown in the image:

[image: The steps of installing the firmware updater]

**What's the cause of this problem? (Why doesn't the windows7x64sp1 recognize me?)**
**Are there anyway to fix it?**

Comment: [Link to the related firmware updater](https://esupport.sony.com/US/p/swu-download.pl?mdl=VPCL116FX&upd_id=5891&os_group_id=6)

Comment: Why would you expect there to be a 2nd CD-ROM device to be listed? This laptop only has one..

Comment: @kisk because I have this laptop for more than 6 years now and it had both the reading and writing capabilities from the beginning. The updater that I've mentioned was one of the official updates when my model drivers were once supported by the [link](https://goo.gl/Ey1Dxi) and this is the [specification file](https://goo.gl/MfZ3mb) of my labtop and as you see [in this photo](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sSBzh.jpg) it should have all the reading and writing capabilities for both CDs And DVDs. But noadays I just can't write on such disks by a laptop.In fact the problem is the same as

Comment: [this](http://goo.gl/wLoMUl) and [this](http://goo.gl/s4QCTl). But the solutions suggested there didn't work for mee

Comment: I assume you downloaded the firmware updater from the Sony support site. Know that laptops of the same model often ship with different components, including DVD/CD drives. Because of this, when you look at the support/downloads section you may see multiple firmware updates for multiple hardware. Just because "Pioneer BD-ROM BCD-TD01" is an available download doesn't mean you have it. If you're having issue reading/writing to your drive there is most likely another issue. Is your BC-5500S4 able to read or write at all?

Comment: it is able to read DVDs but is not able to detect blank DVDs. It can neither read CDs nor write them. But it was able to do all these 4 tasks, before.

Comment: Your problem is most likely your upper/lower filters caused by your previous/current burning software. Since this doesn't answer your original question I'll post it here. This is likely your fix: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929461

Comment: @kisk but [there's no upper or lower filter here](http://s6.picofile.com/file/8257307126/1111.JPG). also have you seen [this post](http://superuser.com/q/1093020/247416). People downvote a lot but don't think that it may cause the OP get bocled of askinh questions

Answer (score 0):

Your target is not found because you are trying to update a device that does not exist. Your laptop only has 1 optical drive, therefor trying to run a firmware update for another optical drive will not work. See comments.

Comment: Maybe this is the cause of my problem but in fact [the solution that you suggested in the comments](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929461), [didn't work for me](http://s6.picofile.com/file/8257307126/1111.JPG)